# Displaying time in the Date Field

Tags: arcgis-desktop, time, date

How would one go about displaying the time that a feature was edited or digitized in a date field so as to display MM/DD/YYYY 12:00:00 AM in the attribute table?

Comment: What software? How do you want to see it, on screen or in a table? Do you already have editor tracking capability and is it enabled?

Comment: ArcGIS 10.4 and I would like it to display in the attributes table in ArcMap. It's not allowing me to click on or enable editor tracker in the Catalog

Comment: That could be because the database/workspace doesn't support editor tracking. Are your features shapefiles? According to the help docs http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//01m600000068000000 file, personal and SDE databases support editor tracking. It could also be that the database has a schema lock from another user or even by yourself.

Comment: @user327 Please edit the question to put the important details in there. Comments will be hidden when there are more than about 5.

Comment: They're features that are stored in a feature dataset within a file geodatabase. I'm heading out for the day, so I won't be able to reply until tomorrow, but I do thank you for your help and consideration today Michael.

Answer (score 2):

ArcGIS has a facility to record the user that created and last modified a feature, either spatially or attribution, it is called [Editor Tracking](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000016p000000) and must be enabled in a feature class to be used. This will not backdate all your features! Users and times will only be recorded from the time that editor tracking is activated.

Editor tracking is available on personal (.mdb), file (.gdb) and SDE databases at the feature class level and is claimed be able to activate on any license level, though I suspect that you would need at least a standard license as well as database permissions to enable on a SDE feature class.

To enable editor tracking fields must be added to the table if they don't already exist and requires a schema lock on the database, which means that *your* instance is the *only instance* that is looking or has looked at the database - even a catalog window that browsed the database last week can still hold a schema lock if it is still active. Note that if the required fields exist but are the wrong type the tool will probably *have a cow*.

It is important to note that all editor tracking is done in UTC and if you don't live in [UTC+0 time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC%C2%B100:00) you might like to convert the datetime to your local time zone, this can be done with the [Convert Time Zone tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//0017000000v3000000) to a different field; the create/update date is a system field and you shouldn't be able to calculate it.

Comment: Unless something has changed, you should have the option to use either UTC or local database time.  That said, if you want to publish the feature class as a feature layer it will need to be UTC (although there are ArcGIS Ideas on removing this limitation)